# How to Edit a write protected read only file

Tags: 16.04, permissions, gedit, snap

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 VM image.I want to edit a file which is owned by root.I tried using sudo chown as well chmod to change the permissions.It was denied.I also tried mount and remount, gksu nautilus, sudo gedit,sudo nano as well as vim editor.Nothing worked.The file read and modify permission can be done only by root owner.The file was installed using snap.Please help me out how to edit the file.

Comment: i tried it now.it cannot save the file.it gives can't open file for writing

Comment: If you want to edit a file inside a snap you need to rebuild it but the config for "thinger" is not inside a snap. It is `/var/snap/thinger-maker-server/common/`. (or better `sudo service snap.thinger-maker-server.thingerd status` should tell you where the config file is)

Comment: How to edit the snap and rebuild it?I am new to it, so please if you can guide me, it would be great.I want to edit the index.html file located at snap/thinger-maker-server/19/console/index.html

Comment: Why? The config for thinger is not inside the snap but is in the directory posted before. By the way: it is open source but not free https://thinger.io/pricing/ So you probably can't edit that file.

Comment: pricing is for people who want to use thinger.io's server.They have no pricing for people using their own server.So as per you is it not possible to edit the index.html file?

Comment: Sure but it also means you will probably not get all the possibilities. Like editing a snap or getting your hands on the source to rebuild it.

Comment: Okay.Thanks for the help brother.I think what you said makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Installed by snap i.e. a file contained in `/snap/<snapname>/<revision>/` somewhere? Snaps are squashfs images, which by definition are read-only. No amount of permissions will change that, I'm afraid.

Comment: I am trying to edit the index.html file which is installed by the following server deployment. http://docs.thinger.io/deployment/  File is located at snap/thinger-maker-server/19/console/index.html